# Any way to permanently fix a reoccuring iOS Dictation error?

Tags: iphone, ios, error, dictionary, voice-dictation

On iOS (15.1, iPhone 13 Pro Max) voice dictation, whenever I say my son's name `Andrew`, it always transcribes it as `Andrew)` with the end parenthesis attached. It's not even like its picking the wrong word and I just need to enunciate clearer, or there would be any reason for this to be in the dictionary this way. It does this every single time, no matter where his name is used in a sentence.

Obviously I say his name quite frequently and its getting really annoying having to repeatedly correct it. Any way to fix this permanently? Google has not yielded any helpful results so far.

Comment: Do you have him as Andrew in your Contacts?  Siri is supposed to look there first for people names.

Comment: @fsb No, hes only 3 lol. I don't have any contacts named Andrew.

Comment: You might want to do that, regardless of his age.  You can put a 'relation' as 'child' for him, that should help.  I had a similar problem and i solved it by doing this as well as adding a nickname to his contact.  Now i can use both the name and nickname.